# Who is currently researching topics concerning applying algebraic topology and/or differential geometry to numerical methods?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, finite-differences

I am interested in pursuing a PhD in mathematics from a top ranked university with a faculty member researching something akin to the following description: applications of algebraic topology and/or differential geometry to numerical methods for PDEs.

A list of a few professors researching anything at all similar to the above description is what I am looking for.

Comment: Which country or countries?

Comment: Prefer United States

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M. Desburn at Caltech.

Anil Hirani at UIUC.

D. Arnold at Minnesota.

And a few more.

Quite a bit of the work in this area has originated from Jerry marsden or his collaborators.
Keywords "Discrete exterior calculus", "Discrete differential geometry",
"symplectic integrators" etc.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the web site [Applied Topology](http://appliedtopology.org/).